# Heroku container:push always re-installs conda packages

Tags: python, heroku, docker, anaconda

I've followed the [python-miniconda tutorial offered by Heroku](https://github.com/heroku-examples/python-miniconda) in order to create my own ML server on Python, which utilizes Anaconda and its packages.

Everything seems to be in order, however each time I wish to update the scripts located at /webapp by entering

```
heroku container:push
```

A complete re-installation of the pip (or rather, Conda) dependencies is performed, which takes quite some time and seems illogical to me. My understanding of both Docker and Heroku frameworks is very shaky, so I haven't been able to find a solution which allows me to push ONLY my code while leaving the container as is without (re?)uploading an entire image.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM heroku/miniconda

ADD ./webapp/requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt

RUN pip install -qr /tmp/requirements.txt

ADD ./webapp /opt/webapp/ 
WORKDIR /opt/webapp

RUN conda install scikit-learn  
RUN conda install opencv

CMD gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT wsgi
```

Comment: Have you tried moving the conda install *before* adding your own app code? That will allow Docker to cache the earlier step.

Comment: @jonrsharpe No I haven't, I'll try it now, thanks

Comment: @jonrsharpe Well, at first I thought it cashed a few dependencies, but still,  each time I re-push the container I get the following lines telling me docker is repushing some layers

`The push refers to a repository [registry.heroku.com/vast-atoll-16962/web]
feaddc106e8f: Pushed
308eb1682146: Pushed
3b47486c7c31: Pushed
6da4924dc20a: Pushing  22.06MB/671.2MB

8cf51ea9d6c7: Layer already exists
f8cb04ba66b3: Layer already exists
c3a60968b69b: Layer already exists
b3fcd0717ee4: Layer already exists
d1e125eef73f: Layer already exists
9e63c5bce458: Layer already exists`

Comment: Layer already exists is good news, it means it's finding the cached version.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Well, I'm not sure this is a contained silution, but it does seem to cache dependencies more than it used to. Thanks a lot

Comment: Same here but with nodejs and `npm i`, looking at the date when this was posted I must start looking for another provider...

Comment: Docker can't cache the subsequent layers if one of the previous layer has been modified. If your `package.json` and/or your app change, each instruction after the `COPY . .` will be re-executed.

Comment: @koral check my answer below.

Comment: This looks like a very interesting answer

Answer (score 1):

This happens because once you updated the webapp directory, you invalidate the build cache. Whatever after this line needs to be rebuild.

When building an image, Docker steps through the instructions in your Dockerfile, executing each in the order specified. As each instruction is examined, Docker looks for an existing image in its cache that it can reuse, rather than creating a new (duplicate) image.

**Once the cache is invalidated, all subsequent Dockerfile commands generate new images and the cache is not used.** ([docs](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#leverage-build-cache))

Hence, to take advantage of the build cache your Dockerfile needs to be defined such as

```
FROM heroku/miniconda

RUN conda install scikit-learn opencv

ADD ./webapp /opt/webapp/
RUN pip install -qr /opt/webapp/requirements.txt

WORKDIR /opt/webapp

CMD gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT wsgi
```

You should merge the two RUN conda commands to a single statement, to [reduce number of layers](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#minimize-the-number-of-layers) in the image. Also, merge the ADD into single command and run pip requirements from a different directory.

Comment: @koral have you checked my suggestion?